# update multiple fields SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi my problem is I want to update a field in 1 table using another field from several tables dependant upon where the item originates my only problem is the table which im trying to update has several of the same values in so am getting 'single row sub-query returns more than 1 row'. I dont mind all of the updated fields with the same value being the same. Heres my SQL:

```
update URL_SET_TAB u
Set U.ITEM_NAME = (select a.PROGRAMME_NAME
                   from (SELECT (nvl(nvl(b.prog_name,c.movie_name), A.URL_1)) as programme_name, a.ID, a.URL_1
                         FROM URL_SET_TAB a, prog_name_lookup b, movie_name_lookup c 
                         where a.url_1 = b.url_1(+) and a.url_1 = C.MOVIE_URL(+)
                         ) a
                   where u.ID = a.ID and U.URL_1 = a.URL_1
                   )
```

Comment: As you have a distinct in the subquery this means that your assertion "all of the updated fields with the same value being the same" is not correct, there are different values from the subquery

Comment: sorry I use oracle and sorry that distinct was added when trying to sort it ill remove it now

Comment: error : single row sub-query return more thaan 1 row' can occur due to multiple values coming from subquery (while selecting programme_name). It may not happen due to multiple rows exist in url_set_tab table.
As you told you are getting multiple rows for on ID and URL_1 values but those values are same then to overcome the error regarding multiple rows you can add `distinct` word while select a.programme_name.

Comment: I had that already as discussed in the previous comments but still gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify a key column which when matched for URL_SET_TAB and inline view a so that the subquery returns only a single record. This is a limitaion of an UPDATE clause.

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: what are my possibilitys if I have no unique key which matches my other queried tables?